# How to search Outlook 2019 user-defined field "ABC" for value "123" and show all matching contacts (using Powershell)?

Tags: powershell, ms-office, outlook-2019

QUESTION:
I'm using Outlook 2019 (on my local computer, no internet, no 365) in Windows 10.
I need to search the user-defined field called "ABC" for value "123" under **Powershell**.

**The aim is to: Show the names of all contacts whose user-defined field "ACB" has the value "123".**

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:**
I gather this code identifies all appointments where the Subject contains "TEST":

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application;
$namespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $outlook -EventName "AdvancedSearchComplete" -Action {
    Write-Host "ADVANCED SEARCH COMPLETE" $Args.Scope
    if ($Args.Results) {  
        foreach ($result in $Args.Results) {
            write-host "=================================================="
            write-host $result.Subject
            write-host $result.ReceivedTime
            write-host $result.SenderName
            write-host "=================================================="
        }
    }
}

Function Get-OutlookInbox {
    $accountsList = $namespace.Folders
    $query = "TEST"
    $filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%"+$query+"%'"

    foreach($account in $accountsList) {
        $scope = $account.FolderPath
        $search = $outlook.AdvancedSearch("'$scope'", $filter, $True)
    }
}
```

Suppose I have a user defined field called "ABC".

For the person whose name is **John Doe**, the value for ABC is **123**

For the person whose name is **Jane Doe**, the value for ABC is **456**

For the person whose name is **Andrew Citizen**, the value for ABC is **123**

What I want is to search the user defined field ABC for the value "123".

The expected result is:

**John Doe**

**Andrew Citizen**

I gather I need to use
**urn:schemas:contacts**

However , how do I query its user-defined fields please?
This other piece of code shows me the content of user-defined field ABC for the person whose firstname is Jane.

```
Function Get-ContactUDF 
{ 
 Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable "OutlookError" 
 $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application -ErrorAction stop -ErrorVariable "ApplicationError" 

 $objNameSpace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $objContacts  = $objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderContacts) 
 $objContact = $objContacts.Items.Find("[FirstName] = ""Jane""") 
 $objProperty = $objContact.UserProperties.Find("ABC") 
 $objProperty.Value 
}
```

What I need is the ***reverse***.  Query UserProperties, in order to show the name of the person(s). How do I do it please? (using Powershell). Thanks.